# Opening Workbook Script Stuck In Loop In Private Sub

Tags: excel, vba

The following Excel VBA script works just fine by itself.

```
Sub OpenSchedule()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set w = Workbooks

src = "S:\File.xls"
w.Open Filename:=src, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True

End Sub
```

But when I named it a private sub and called it from a main sub with passing variables...

```
Private Sub OpenSchedule(loadtype, appt, partial)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set w = Workbooks

src = "S:\File.xls"
w.Open Filename:=src, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True

'Continue Code.......
```

It gets stuck on w.Open Filename in a weird loop where it repeatedly opens and closes it in under a second.  I have to break to get out.

Edit:   Code is actually being called from a secondary sub with variables..

```
Sub main()

'code
Call SecondSub(a,b,c,d)

End Sub

Private Sub SecondSub(a,b,c,d)

'code
Call OpenSchedule(c,d,e,f)
End Sub

Private Sub OpenSchedule(c,d,e,f)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set w = Workbooks

msgbox "Break"

src = "S:\File.xls"
w.Open Filename:=src, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True

'Continue Code.......
```

I put in a Msgbox break in it and determined that when it tries to open that other workbook it resets to the top of the OpenSchedule sub, because the msgbox line keeps executing.

Comment: When you mean workbook script, do you mean VBA or VBS?

Comment: It is a VBA script.

Comment: Does it somehow stays in a loop on just that one line? What does it do when you go through using F8?

Comment: Yes, it stays on that line and just opens and shuts it.  It's really weird.

Comment: Can't recreate the problem, with that code.
What's the next line of code?

Comment: You know what, I just realized that the code is being called from a secondary sub, not from the main sub.

Comment: And `File.xls` has a macro that runs on open?

Comment: No. File.xls has no macros.. just some data.

Comment: How do you call Main?

Comment: When I'm finished, Main will run on a timer.  Right now I'm just running it from inside VBA.